# How do I create a table using python code, too then view in my browser?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Was hoping for some guidance in how to create a nicely styled table I can then view in my web browser. So far I have web scraped a page to create a .csv file and then using pandas in python I have created a table from my csv file, the code below shows my pandas code which creates my table. This code works and in my terminal I can see the results show the table in code format but I want too be able to see my table in a browser and style it nicely. I am thinking of using flask to do this but I cant get this too work, any advice would be greatly appreciated. The flask code I have written is also below but is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['cap', 'title', 'price']
df = pd.read_csv('asdawhiskey.csv', names=columns)

print(items.to_html())


set FLASK_APP=AsdaWhiskeyTable.py
$env: FLASK_APP="AsdaWhiskeyTable.py"
from flask import *
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/tables")
def show_tables():
    data = pd.read_csv('asdawhiskey.csv')


data.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
data.index.name=None
asda = data.loc[data.product=='whiskey']
return render_template('view.html', tables=[items.to_html()],
                       titles = ['na', 'Asda Whiskey'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a dataframe and just want a way to convert it to html. The example below creates a toy dataframe and writes it to an html file. The [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) documentation contains additional arguments to further tailor the output. Hope this helps.

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe of random items
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# convert dataframe to html
html = df.to_html()

# Option to print output to terminal
# print(html)

# open file and write
file = open("table.html", 'w')
file.write(html)
file.close
```